# Using Drupal cms with Java application

Tags: java, drupal, web-applications, content-management-system

I have java based web-application.. I want to modify its content through Drupal 7.Is it possible by drupal 7 to manage the contents java based web-app (site)?

I have googled i couldnt find it... Everywhere i could see only the predefined folder structure for drupal site but java web-app has different folder structure . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although it's a complex process and you will need Drupal and Java development experience. Your Java based web-app would need to expose an API, to manage its content, that Drupal could call. This API would typically be via REST or web services. You would then need to create your own Drupal module, with appropriate *hooks* in it, which would call the REST/web service.